# How to read(in), print(out) value to text file by Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on with my simple server. And i need a little data(number) to be used for my project, but i don't want to use database(cuz i don't like SQL). So is there any way that i could save my data in file text and use data in that file text?[image]

I want to use Js to print number from roll call program.htm to hr.txt and then i want read number from hr.txt to roll call program.htm which make a perfect data storage.I tested this kind of saving data in my c++ IDE and it worked, but i don't know if it can work on a server. So can you guys help me out?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: I don't know the code syntax for in and out file so you know!

Comment: It is impossible, the javascript just run in client side, how do you think if client side code can write anything to your server? You need a server side what handles the request from your client side (html, javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code for saving the data as a text file and loading in the HTML.
You can modify this code and use as per your convenience.

```
function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToSave = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
    var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
    var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}

function loadFileAsText()
{
    var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
    {
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
```